# How to retrieve Downloaded content in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app i've downloaded a mp3 file and I stored it by giving a file name to write **abc.mp3**, while storing it the file path shown is this:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9AFC500A-91D5-421B-8A5F-19A239456353/Documents/abc.mp3
```

and when I play it the path is

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9AFC500A-91D5-421B-8A5F-19A239456353/Documents/abc.mp3
```

**the code to play is**:

```
NSURL* songUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:songUrlString];
mediaPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:url ];  //This is AVPlayer Instance
[mediaPlayer play];
```

**The code to download is:**

-

```
(void)downloadContent:(NSString*)stringURL{
    stringURL = [stringURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    currentURL = stringURL;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData  timeoutInterval:60];
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self     startImmediately:YES];   
}


- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    progress.hidden = NO;
    [receivedData setLength:0];
    expectedBytes = [response expectedContentLength];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    float progressive = (float)[receivedData length] / (float)expectedBytes;
    progress.value = progressive;
    NSLog(@"%f",progressive);
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:    (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",documentsDirectory);
    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abc.mp3"];
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %lu bytes of data",(unsigned long)[receivedData length]);
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [receivedData writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];
    progress.hidden = YES;
}
```

**So finally the Problem is its not Playing the content. I even don't know whether the content is written to file or not.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33691826/3134130

Comment: check first file successfully written or not by NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];

Comment: if data is nil then file has not available on the path

Comment: @johnykumar Its working ... You are awesome man... You write the answer I'll accept yours coz you are first

Comment: @kb920 thanks dude...

Comment: no problem bro,you can accept answer of the link which i shared.just vote up my comments that will help others also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "given" an arbitrary documents folder by the system (that is `NSDocumentDirectory`) that you can't guarantee it's full exact path.
To solve this, you should, "build" the path every time you need the file from it, the same way you did when you wrote the file:

```
//build the path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abc.mp3"];

//then you can do:
NSURL* songUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];
mediaPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:url ];
[mediaPlayer play];
```

Note that I simply used your code that you use to build the path when downloading the file.